# Cannot get Uri for an in-memory object because of missing PackageStore class

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.packaging

I need to get the URI of an in-memory bitmap because the class I want to use accepts only bitmap URIs, not `byte[]` data. Also, I don't want to create temporary files for this purpose but operate only with the memory. In `.NET Framework` I can do this:

```
Uri GetMemoryBitmapUri()
{
    MemoryStream packStream = new MemoryStream();
    Package pack = Package.Open(packStream, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    Uri packUri = new Uri("packUri:");
    PackageStore.AddPackage(packUri, pack);  // we don't have PackageStore in .NET
    Uri packPartUri = new Uri("/bitmap.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
    PackagePart packPart = pack.CreatePart(packPartUri, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
    var bitmapBytes = GetInMemoryBitmapData();
    packPart.GetStream().Write(bitmapBytes, 0, bitmapBytes.Length);
    return PackUriHelper.Create(packUri, packPart.Uri);
}
```

And it works - the reference returned from `GetMemoryBitmapUri()` can be passed to the method of the class I would like to use and the bitmap is drawn.

But I have a problem when trying to do this in `.NET 7` since there is no longer `PackageStore` class in `System.IO.Packaging` and so I cannot make `PackageStore.AddPackage` call. How can I handle this problem?

Comment: use `PackageRegistry` class instead

Comment: @HamidMohammadi I don't see `PackageRegistry` class in the `System.IO.Packaging`, where is it located?